# unable to import 'econml' in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have installed the 'econml' package but when  I try to import DML, using :

```
from econml.dml import DML
```

I am getting the following error:

'ImportError: cannot import name 'show_config' from 'numpy' (unknown location)'

I am wondering how can I fix this issue.

Comment: do you also have numpy installed?

Comment: yes, I already have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Find any file named as "numpy.py" in your script directory and change it into another name.
2. Delete any file named as "numpy.pyc" or any other file generated while compiling your code.